# .apply() to object instance of class python

Tags: python, oop, pytorch, tensor

what do we mean and why do we use the .apply() function in python

like in this example:- is it the same as we use in pandas?

```
func = MyFunction()
x = torch.tensor([6., 6.], requires_grad=True) 
y = func.apply(x)
```

```
class MyFunction(Function):

    @staticmethod
    def forward(ctx: Any, x: Tensor) -> Tensor:

        ctx.save_for_backward(x) 

        func_value = (
            (x[0]-6)**2 + x[1]**2 - x[0]*x[1]
        )

        return func_value

    def backward(ctx: Any, grad_output: Any) -> Any:

        x = ctx.saved_tensors[0]
        print('x',x)

        grad_x = torch.tensor([ 2*x[0] - x[1] - 12, -x[0] + 2*x[1]])
        return grad_output * grad_x
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: What is `MyFunction()`? Please edit this question to add the definition.

Comment: @Craig, please take a look now

Comment: It's still not a [mre], but it appears that this is coming from PyTorch and is described in https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/autograd.html#torch.autograd.Function

Comment: This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.